# set selectedValue of combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox 'cbSkillLevel' to which I am binding data as shown bellow to populate the list. It works fine. I have a list box with items, based on the items selection I need to set different value to the 'cbSkillLevel'. How do I set the value of combobox to the value I want.

What I tried is bellow.

Your help much appreciated.

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" x:Name="cbSkillLevel" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SkillsPage, Path=setIsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontSize="26" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>

List<Lookup> skillLevel = dbOperation.getLookupData("Skill_Level");
cbSkillLevel.ItemsSource = skillLevel;


private void lbSkills_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   clearFields();
   clearTopicsForm();
   var skillobj = (lbSkills.SelectedItem as Skill);

   if (skillobj != null)  
   { 
       selected_SkillDescription = skillobj.SkillDescription;
       tbNotes.Text = skillobj.Notes;
       tbDescription.Text = selected_SkillDescription;
       /*I TRIED THE BELLOW OPTION BUT DID NOT WORK.*/
       //cbSkillLevel.SelectedItem = skillobj.SkillLevel;
       //cbSkillLevel.SelectedIndex = cbSkillLevel.Items.IndexOf(skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString());                
       //cbSkillLevel.SelectedIndex = 1;
       //cbSkillLevel.ItemsSource = tempListSkillLevel;
       cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString();
       cbSkillType.SelectedItem = skillobj.SkillType;
       tbWarningWeeks.Text = skillobj.WarningWeeks.ToString();
       dpValidFrom.Date = skillobj.ValidFrom;
       dpValidUntil.Date = skillobj.ValidUntil;
       /*load topics for this skill*/
       loadTopicsFromDB(skillobj.SkillDescription);
       //set the fields as read only
       setIsEnabled = false;
       addEditButton();            
     }
  }
```

I though using 'cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString();' should work, but it does not. My guess is cuz the binding is set to the value 'Value'

```
<TextBlock FontSize="26" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Value}" />
```

And while setting a value I am assigning from Skill object. How can I set value 
'cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString();'

```
class Skill 
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey,   SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SkillDescription { get; set; }
    public string SkillType { get; set; }
    public string SkillLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }
    public int WarningWeeks { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}

class Lookup
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int LookupId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedItem probobly don't work since the objects are differnt physcials objects, created in seperate lists.
That you used {Binding Value} isn't the problem, that is only the visual representation of your objects and have nothing to do with the selection. The thing you need to do is to tell the combobox WHAT value that is the "SelectedValue" on that object. that is done in the XAML and suggestly to Value since that seams to be unice to your objects(?)

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Value" ...
```

Then this should work:

```
cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = skillobj.SkillLevel.Value;
```

Comment: Hi 'Value' is not unique to both objects, in Lookup object its 'Value' and in Skill it is 'SkillLevel'. that is why I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Hmm, LookupId is that the identifyer? What ever it is that they have incommon or create a new property if needed (can consist of data from other Propertys, pref. read only). And use that instead of "Value" on my two code snippets.

Comment: no keys are common between them and i can not add any property as that will be the table structure.

Comment: How does the SkillLevel class look like? And how does it map to a Lookup, what values is the same if they are "the same"?

Comment: hi there is no SkillLevel class, there is Skill class and Lookup class. I am setting the item source of the combo box to data from Lookup. while setting the selectedValue I am trying to set from the Skill object which has the skillLevel which is equal to one of the items from Lookup object.

Comment: your right, you dont have a SkillLevel class (to tierd I guess...) You say that you wanna match the string called skillLevel with the object Lookup, but Lookup have 3 properties, so you need to define for me how they are alike. is it "skillLevel = Lookup.Value"? or "skillLevel = Lookup.Type + Lookup.Value" ???

Comment: must have been a busy weekend?. So basically I have got the itemSource for the combobox coming from table based on class Lookup(Properties - LookupId,Type and Value). As per mycombobox binding i set the itemSource to data from Lookup table.
I have a Skill table which has properties(ID,Skilldesciption, SkillLevel and so on.) I am trying to set the selectedvalue of the combobox to SkillLevel property from Skill table (cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString())
skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString() has one of the values from the itemSource(Lookup table - value - Value) hope its clear:)

Comment: I tried 
 
Within selected changed I took another list which is of Lookup type (the one combobox is looking for) and added the 'Value' field from skillObj . and then i tried setting the selected value but still does not work. something like this List<Lookup> tempListSkillLevel = new List<Lookup>(); tempListSkillLevel.Add(new Lookup { Value = skillobj.SkillLevel }); then cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = tempListSkillLevel[0]; but always selectedvalue is shown as null

Comment: Did add SelectedValuePath="Value" too? (in the bombobox xamll)

Comment: And you need to use tempListSkillLevel[0].Value

Comment: I have note added selectedValuePath but i have tried tempListSkillLevel[0].Value. do you think both in combination will work? leme try now

Comment: That works for me now. thank you very much. Saved my life. you are definitely not tired

Comment: U did mention all this in your first post. i did try it but some reason it did not work. It does now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

ItemSource is a List of Lookup, so the only way to set the "selected" must also be of Lookup type.

```
cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = skillobj.SkillLevel.ToString();
```

This will only work if you already have established an ItemSource with

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

ComoboBox is an ItemsControl. You can see a detailed info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Within selected changed I took another list which is of Lookup type (the one combobox is looking for) and added the 'Value' field from skillObj . and then i tried setting the selected value but still does not work. something like this
List<Lookup> tempListSkillLevel = new List<Lookup>();
            tempListSkillLevel.Add(new Lookup { Value = skillobj.SkillLevel });
then
cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = tempListSkillLevel[0];
but always selectedvalue is shown as null

Answer (score 0):

Add DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath to your xaml bindings that is DisplayMemberPath is what property of object should be shown to the user and SelectedValuePath is what property it selects internally so its like this for example if i want to bind my fruits collection to combobox, i would like display fruit name but select its id so my properties will be

```
 DisplayMemberPath = "FruitName"
 SelectedValuePath = "FruitId"
```

And later in your selectionchanged event, you can set its value with cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue. In our example, it will be the fruit id as we bound it as SelectedValuePath.

Comment: Within selected changed I took another list which is of Lookup type (the one combobox is looking for) and added the 'Value' field from skillObj . and then i tried setting the selected value but still does not work. something like this List<Lookup> tempListSkillLevel = new List<Lookup>(); tempListSkillLevel.Add(new Lookup { Value = skillobj.SkillLevel }); then cbSkillLevel.SelectedValue = tempListSkillLevel[0]; but always selectedvalue is shown as null

Comment: Hi in your example FruiName and FruitId are of the same obj? in my case itemSource of the object Lookup and the selectedValue I am trying to set is of different object SKill. any idea?